# Selection of Calendar event query

Tags: android, calendar

I try to read out events from a specific calendar. Following is the code I try to use. But I dont know how the selection has to look like. I want to use the calendar id for the selection. Without the selection (null) it reads out all calendars, but I just want one.
A query looks like this:

```
public final Cursor query (Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder)
```

selection:
A filter declaring which rows to return, formatted as an SQL WHERE clause (excluding the WHERE itself). Passing null will return all rows for the given URI.

This code is the first try with a selection:

```
            Uri.Builder builder = Instances.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();
            ContentUris.appendId(builder, now - DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);
            ContentUris.appendId(builder, now + DateUtils.DAY_IN_MILLIS);

            Cursor mCursor = null;
            final String[] projection = new String[]
            { CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, CalendarContract.Events.DTEND};

            mCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                builder.build(), projection, Instances._ID  + calendarID, null, null);
                mCursor.moveToFirst();
```

Thats the error from above code:

```
09-29 00:07:41.800: E/AndroidRuntime(14507): FATAL EXCEPTION: TweetCollectorTimer
09-29 00:07:41.800: E/AndroidRuntime(14507): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id3: , while compiling: SELECT title, dtstart, dtend FROM Instances INNER JOIN view_events AS Events ON (Instances.event_id=Events._id) WHERE (begin<=? AND end>=?) AND (_id3)
09-29 00:07:41.800: E/AndroidRuntime(14507):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)
09-29 00:07:41.800: E/AndroidRuntime(14507):    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
09-29 00:07:41.800: E/AndroidRuntime(14507):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:358)
09-29 00:07:41.800: E/AndroidRuntime(14507):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:311)
09-29 00:07:41.800: E/AndroidRuntime(14507):    at de.ring.AppService$1.run(AppService.java:96)
09-29 00:07:41.800: E/AndroidRuntime(14507):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
```

**EDIT:**

Thanks a lot, I changes it to:

```
            mCursor =   getContentResolver().query(
                    builder.build(), projection, Instances.CALENDAR_ID  + " = ?",
                    new String[]{""+calendarID}, null);
```

Its important to use CALENDAR_ID and not just _ID.

Comment: i fix your problem then you changed the question with another error !!! you should post a new question with new error !!

Comment: Sorry, the error wasn't real, I just used the wrong ID therefore I got this error. I changed the EDIT with the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make this

```
  getContentResolver().query(
                    builder.build(), projection, Instances._ID  + "=?",
new String[]{""+calendarID}, null);
```

instead of this

```
getContentResolver().query(
                builder.build(), projection,
 Instances._ID  + calendarID, null, null);
```

since the 3rd parameter take the selection string and you pass this `Instances._ID  + calendarID` it will be evaluate to this

```
SELECT ........ WHERE _id3;
```

it append the number of the calendar id to the column name .