# How to find Events of Calender between two dates in android

Tags: java, android, android-alarms, android-event

As i am new in `Android`, i have to make an android app which can find the events list between two dates like: 23-02-14 to 24-02-14. I am not getting those events which i have added manually on calender like birthday of my friend, it shows the whole list of events which are predefined in it like: Mothers' day.

So my question is how can i do this. any hint please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12648066/selection-of-calendar-event-query and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can go through below link.

[Getting events from calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883938/getting-events-from-calendar), 
[How to get all the events from calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13232717/how-to-get-all-the-events-from-calendar)

If it will help mark right to accept this as your answer.